# How to check STDERR in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to debug a file upload script using the AWS SDK for PHP.

There's a method called [`enable_debug_mode`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/enable_debug_mode) in the SDK.

But on the reference page, it says `Enables HTTP request/response header logging to STDERR.`

How do I check STDERR while debugging with a browser?

Answer (score 1):

per [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) that depends where are you running the script. If *cli* will be the console, otherwise apache error log (if you are running apache)